# Using an array as an attribute to modify it Java

Tags: java

my friend has programmed a Breakout game in java. I know C++, which tranfers relatively well to java.

I had a problem when trying to insert a MultiBall brick.

Here are the relevent bits of my function:

```
private Balle[] balle;
public BriqueMultiBalle(Balle[] bal) {
        super();
        balle = bal;
        SCORE = 100;
    }
public void touched() {
        visible = false;
        balle[Balle.getNInstance()].makeVisible();
    }
```

I get no error but I found out when debugging that *balle* corresponds to a null pointer. I tried using these different declarations, however, none of them worked:

1.

```
    public BriqueMultiBalle(Balle[] bal) {
                super();
                for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                    {
                         balle[i] = bal[i];
                    }
                SCORE = 100;
            }
```

2.

```
public BriqueMultiBalle(Balle[] bal) {
            super();
            balle = new Balle[](bal);
            SCORE = 100;
        }
```

However, these methods do not work.

Thanks,

Ghi102

Comment: Which constructor are you calling, the default, or the one where you pass in a `Balle[]`? If the latter, are you sure you're passing in an initialized `Balle[]`?

Comment: How are you creating the `Balle[]` that you're passing in to the constructor?  Perhaps you can show us the code where you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a null pointer on balle because you never initialize the array, you leave it as

```
private Balle[] balle;
```

Try initializing you code

```
balle = new Balle[bal.length];
for(int i = 0; i < bal.length; i++){
        balle[i] = bal[i];
}
```

Here's an example I wrote using an int array. Same concept, just apply it to your object.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    int[] arrayInts;
    int[] originalInts = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    arrayInts = new int[originalInts.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < originalInts.length; i++){
        arrayInts[i] = originalInts[i];
    }

    originalInts[0] = 10;
    for (int i : arrayInts) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```